# Two corresponding sequences in a set $A$ and its closure $\overline A$

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

So I saw the following statement in a proof in my notes from a course in Functional Analysis and I have difficulty understanding it.

Let $X$ be a normed linear space and $A \subset X$. Also, let $[a_n]$ be a sequence in $\overline A$, the closure of $A$. Then there is sequence $[b_n]$ in $A$, such that $||a_n-b_n|| < \frac{1}{n}, \forall n \in \mathbb N.$

Why is it so? Thanks for any explanation.

My thoughts:
Since every $a_n$ is a limit point of $A$, then every neighborhood of it, $B(a_n, \epsilon)$ has at least one element other than $a_n$ itself. Name this other element as $b_n$. Since $\epsilon >0$ was arbitrary, it could have been $1/n$. Am I right so far?

Also, I called these two sequences *corresponding* to each other. Does their correspondence have a specific name in the literature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s true in any metric space. Let $n\in\Bbb Z^+$; $a_n\in\operatorname{cl}A$, so $A\cap B\left(a_n,\frac1n\right)\ne\varnothing$, where

$$B(x,r)=\{y\in X:\|y-x\|<r\}$$

for each $x\in X$ and real number $r>0$. Let $b_n\in A\cap B\left(x_n,\frac1n\right)$; then $\|a_n-b_n\|<\frac1n$.

Comment: Thanks so much. I think I just wrote a similar (though not as elegant as yours) answer in the edit. Could you please answer the final question in the edited post? (Does the correspondence between these two sequences have a name?)

Comment: @Neutrino: Yes, what you did is fine, except that it’s actually possible that $a_n$ is the only point of $A$ in $B\left(a_n,\frac1n\right)$, so you can’t actually guarantee that $b_n\ne a_n$. For instance, $X$ might be $\Bbb R$, $A=(0,1)\cup\{3\}$, and $a_1=3$. I’m not aware of any name for the relationship between these two sequences.